# Backbone View inheritance sharing properties

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am extending Backbone views like:

```
var baseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    fruits : [],
    listFruits : function() {
        console.log(this.fruits);
    }
});

var firstView = baseView.extend({
    initialize : function() {
        this.fruits.push("apple");
    }
});

var secondView = baseView.extend({
    initialize : function() {
        this.fruits.push("pear");
    }
});


var firstViewInstance = new firstView(); // ["apple", "pear"]
var secondViewInstance = new secondView(); // ["apple", "pear"]

firstViewInstance.listFruits();
secondViewInstance.listFruits();
```

To my mind, `firstViewInstance` and `secondViewInstance` should be entirely separate, but they are clearly related.  How can I achieve two separate view objects, both inheriting from a common base, but *not* sharing data?

EDIT:
Based on answers below I have an updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/qZ7SU/ which seems to solve this problem.  I'm still not entirely clear what is going on, but I think explicitly attaching `fruits[]` to `this`, creates it as an instance variable, rather than attaching it to the prototype.

Comment: Your problem here is that `[]` is an array, therefore an object, so is unique is the prototype and all of your views are manipulating the same. A simple solution but involving a lot of boilerplate would be to add this.fruits = [] in the initialize function. Another one would be to override the constructor of baseView. I'll explain that part is you're interested. I'll try to think of another solution too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the reference to the original `fruits`-property is the one being copied to the children view. See [underscore.js `extend`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-76)

```
_.extend = function(obj) {
  each(slice.call(arguments, 1), function(source) {
    if (source) {
      for (var prop in source) {
        obj[prop] = source[prop];
      }
    }
  });
  return obj;
};
```

To inherit from the common base, but not share data, you need to initialize the not-shared properties in the initialize-function.

```
var baseView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this._initializeBase();
  },

  _initializeBase: function() {
    this.fruits = [];
  },

  listFruits : function() {
    console.log(this.fruits);
  }
});

var firstView = baseView.extend({
  initialize : function() {
    this._initializeBase();
    this.fruits.push("apple");
  }
});
```

This way the property will be added to the object when it is initialized and the data will not be shared.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up a bit, I've taken what you said, but done it slightly differently by calling the prototype initialize, and updated the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/uNBSW/10/ which now seems to do what I want.  I still find the whole Javascript prototype inheritance very confusing.  Much prefer the classic OOP concepts!

Comment: Javascript has its gotchas, but it also provides a much more flexible way of doing certain things

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a more detailed [blog post](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/backbone-and-inheritance) about this but the easiest way is to provide a custom constructor that ensures `fruits` is created on the prototype of each subviews, and not on the `baseView.prototype` which all subviews inherit.

```
var baseView = Backbone.View.extend({
  constructor: function() {
    this.fruits = [];
    Backbone.View.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  listFruits : function() {
    console.log(this.fruits);
  }
});

var firstView = baseView.extend({
    initialize : function() {
        this.fruits.push("apple");
    }
});

var secondView = baseView.extend({
    initialize : function() {
        this.fruits.push("pear");
    }
});


var firstViewInstance = new firstView(); // ["apple"]
var secondViewInstance = new secondView(); // ["pear"]
```

Comment: Agreed, this should be the marked answer. Calling `initialize` from inherited views is an anti-pattern imo.